# C# Append List of record in another List of record

Tags: c#, .net, list

How can we append the records in a List in another list of records. I tried using the code below but I can't get the output that I expected.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;                   
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> List1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> List2 = new List<string>();
            
            List1.Add("Hello");
            List1.Add("Hi");
            List1.Add("Bonjour");
            
            List2.Add("John");
            List2.Add("Mike");
            List2.Add("Peter");
            
            List2.AddRange(List2);
            
            foreach(var item in List1 )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

My expected output should be the following :

```
    Hello John
    Hi Mike
    Bonjour Peter
```

Thanks

Comment: If Length of List1 and List2 are the same, you should use for loop to iterate thru list and join strings from the respective elements of the list.

Comment: Thanks, @ChetanRanpariya, but what if the list count is not the same?

Comment: What output do you expect if the list count is not the same? Can you provide some sample input data and the expected output?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The function `List.AddRange` will append the new collection to the existing collection.

i'm not aware of any out of the box function that can accomplish what you're trying to do, but a simple for loop does the job.

```
List<string> List1 = new List<string>();
List<string> List2 = new List<string>();
var list3 = new List<string>();

List1.Add("Hello");
List1.Add("Hi");
List1.Add("Bonjour");

List2.Add("John");
List2.Add("Mike");
List2.Add("Peter");

for (int i = 0; i < List1.Count; i++)
{
    list3.Add(List1[i]);
    list3.Add(List2[i]);
}

foreach (var item in list3)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Comment: "i'm not aware of any out of the box function that can accomplish what you're trying to do" - there is: Linq's `Zip`.

Comment: Thanks for this sir, This is what I'm looking for.
I made some changes in 
 list3.Add(List1[i]);
        list3.Add(List2[i]);
I changed it to
list3.Add(List1[i] + "" + List2[i]);
so that I will get my expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Use Linq's `Zip` function. It joins each element at the same index from two collections:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            List<string> greetings = new List<string>();
            List<string> names     = new List<string>();
            
            greetings.Add("Hello");
            greetings.Add("Hi");
            greetings.Add("Bonjour");
            
            names.Add("John");
            names.Add("Mike");
            names.Add("Peter");
            
            List<string> combined = Enumerable
                .Zip( greetings, names, ( g, n ) => g + " " + n )
                .ToList();

            foreach( String c in combined ) Console.WriteLine( c );
        }
    }
```

`Zip` itself is an extension-method, but my code above calls it using the non-extension static method so you can see there's no "magic" going on.

Ordinarily it would look like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> combined = greetings.Zip( names, ( g, n ) => g + " " + n );

foreach( String c in combined ) Console.WriteLine( c );
```

Or just:

```
foreach( String c in greetings.Zip( names, ( g, n ) => g + " " + n ) ) Console.WriteLine( c );
```

Or even:

```
foreach( String c in new[] { "Hello", "Hi", "Bonjour" }.Zip( new[] { "John", "Mike", "Peter" }, ( g, n ) => g + " " + n ) ) Console.WriteLine( c );
```

Answer (score -1):

```cs
            List<string> List1 = new List<string>();
            List<string> List2 = new List<string>();

            List1.Add("Hello");
            List1.Add("Hi");
            List1.Add("Bonjour");

            List2.Add("John");
            List2.Add("Mike");
            List2.Add("Peter");

            List2.AddRange(List2);

            for (int i = 0; i < List1.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(List1.ElementAt(i) + " " + List2.ElementAt(i));
            }
```